# How to compile examples from qxmpp library?

Tags: qt

Good afternoon guys! 
I'm a beginner on QT cross-platform env. So, that I got a trouble
with compiling some examples from qxmpp library; 
I've tried but it says: "cannot find lqxmpp_d0"
I would be grateful if anybody could assist me on...
Thanks beforehand

Comment: Which OS? Are you using Qt Creator or the command line.  Is it these examples (http://code.google.com/p/qxmpp/wiki/UsingQXmpp)?

Comment: You will need to compile QXmpp first and then link it to your project to fix the symbols not found compiler error.